# Redux-saga how to pass parameters to request inside saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

I've got some code i've to update. It's not my code so i don't want too many changes. It uses redux-saga and axios. I want to pass some arguments to saga

my saga in **sagas.js**

```
export function* getInfoSaga() {
    while (true) {
        yield take(mutations.GET_INFO);
        const url1 = `${url}/api/getInfo/1-100`;
        const logInfo = yield axios.get<any>(url1).then(response => response);
        yield put(mutations.setInfo(logInfo.data.data));
    }
}
```

**mutations.js**

```
export const GET_INFO = 'GET_INFO';

export const getInfo = () => ({
    type: GET_INFO,
});
```

The sagas are run within **index.js**

```
const s = sagas as any;

for (const saga in s) {
    sagaMiddleware.run(s[saga]);
}
```

And in some file the action is run by buton with event:

```
 onClick={() => dispatch({
                        type: 'GET_INFO',
                    })}
```

I wanted to pass some parameters to modify the request url, i tried gettin additional object in dipatch request and ading arguments to generators in sagas.js and mutatuions.js hovewer i got an error with **cannot access prperty of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: Pass payload and just assign return value from 'take'

```
onClick={() => dispatch({
  type: 'GET_INFO',
  payload: {
    key1: value1
    // other values here
  }
})}

export function* getInfoSaga() {
   const action = yield take(mutations.GET_INFO);
   // action.payload.key1
}
```

Comment: I'm using TypeSript and getting an error :
```TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'payload' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.```
With:
```export function* getInfoSaga({ payload } : { payload : IPayload}) {```
The same goes for type any

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
onClick={() => dispatch({
  type: 'GET_INFO',
  url: 'your/url/goes/here'
})}

export function* getInfoSaga(action) {
    while (true) {
        yield take(mutations.GET_INFO);
        const url1 = `${action.url}/api/getInfo/1-100`;
        const logInfo = yield axios.get<any>(url1).then(response => response);
        yield put(mutations.setInfo(logInfo.data.data));
    }
}
```